# Calculating the amount of overlapping days between two ranges

Tags: excel-formula

I have a set of Elements all with a start date and a projected end date.  I wish display the number of days each element overlaps with every row on the Holidays section. - I will use this as a guide to how far I need to extend the Timeline - End:

[image]

I have tried using `MMULT`, `TRANSPOSE`, `INDEX` and `ROW` in combination but throws `!VALUE`.

The current formula I tried using was:

```
=MMULT((TRANSPOSE($C$4+ROW(C19:INDEX($C:$C, $D$20-$C$4+1))-1)>=$C$20:$C$40)*(TRANSPOSE($C$4+ROW(C19:INDEX($C:$C, $D$20-$C$4+1))-1)<=D20:D40), ROW(C19:INDEX($C:$C, $D$4-$C$4+1))^0)
```

I expect the number of days that the all 'Holidays' over lap with each row in the Elements section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (since I cannot read/get which 2 ranges that you intent to compare..) that range1 is from  to  and range2 is from  to , with these values are located in A1= , B1= , A2= , B2= . Do :

```
=if((if(B2<B1,B2,B1)-if(A2>A1,A2,A1))>=0,(if(B2<B1,B2,B1)-if(A2>A1,A2,A1)),"no overlap")
```

Idea : get the earliest end date, minus the latest start date.

please share if it works/not.